# OpenERP 7 and jasper exports, Jasper report not working yet

Tags: jasper-reports, compatibility, openerp-7

I try to duplicate an OpenERP 7 server and a Jasper server, the existing servers are already connected and working.

I exported the OpenERP server Virtual machine and put it in my LAN at 192.168.42.40,

I exported the Jasper server Virtual machine and put it in my LAN at 192.168.42.41,

In OpenERP Configuration, in the menu Jasper Report > Configuration JasperServer I have set the host at 192.168.42.41. 
When I click on Check Auth button, it's OK.

But when I try to do a report, I've got this error

```
[1]jsexception.error.creating.connection

(<class 'openerp.addons.jasper_server.jasperlib.ServerError'>,
ServerError('[1]jsexception.error.creating.connection',), 
<traceback object at 0x7f1dc9262f38>)
```

I think it failed to create a connection between OpenERP and Jasper, but I don't know how to solve it.

Ideas ?

Thank you, and sorry if my english is not perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) On Jasper report:

openerp > databases : right click > Add new ressource > Datasource

Fill fields.

2) On iReport :

openerp > reports : right click > Add > Folder

Copy or create a report.

3) On iReport :

openerp > bases: right click > Add > Folder

On this folder right click > Add > Jasper server report With the same name as the database name !

Set the 1) datasource in the Datasource field,

and the 2) report in the JRXML report.